# ROS Multiple Computers - adding a 2nd master

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, roscore, multiple-machines

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Current Scenario**

- Robot + Camera
- Laptop

The **robot** runs `roscore` and the **laptop** runs `rosrun rviz rviz`. On the **laptop** I'm able to see the camera footage from the **robot** just fine.

**Question**

I want to add another **robot + camera** to the equation. How can I make my **laptop** listen to the `roscore`'s of each **robot**?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231523/ros-multiple-computers---adding-a-2nd-master/) by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on ROS Answers with karma: 396 on 2016-04-09

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on 2016-04-09**:
excuse me i don't know the response.
i want to ask you how laptop like node communicate on WiFi with Robot?

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-09**:
Read this http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines then this [http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~cteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Ecteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can launch the `roscore` on your laptop (or any ROS device that stays connected during the experiment. it could be one of the robots) and then launch your two robots with `roslaunch` commands. If they are on the same network and you have correctly specified the `ROS_MASTER_URI` you should have no issues.

By default, the current version of ROS does not allow to have multiple ROS masters on the same network, but efforts have been made to implement this feature, you can have a look at the following packages :

- http://wiki.ros.org/multimaster_fkie
- http://wiki.ros.org/rocon_launch

This being said you might want to start working with a single master first and transition to multiple master only if needed. If you are working with a reliable network you probably don't need multiple masters.

Also, if you have multiple robots, make sure that you launch them in separate namespaces (e.g `/robot1/`,`/robot2/` to avoid confusions and conflicts ...

---

Originally posted by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) with karma: 883 on 2016-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-10**:
I would really like to go with one master idea but I'm finding that the camera only streams if it's connect to a machine running `roscore` (aka a "master"). Is it possible to go the other way?

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-10**:
After I wrote the previous comment I thought I something I might be doing wrong. I made the change and now everything works as I wanted with only one master. The issue was that I have to specify my `ROS_IP` for each machine in the system.

**Comment by [MAlShamsi2323](https://answers.ros.org/users/26557/malshamsi2323/) on 2016-04-11**:
dear jack
I have been facing a similar problem.
how can I specify my ROS_IP to have two devices working with one master?

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2016-04-11**:
Just make sure that each device has the environment variable `ROS_IP` set to its own unique IP on the network interface that you are using, and `ROS_MASTER_URI` set to the IP of the ROS master. http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-11**:
What al-dev said. Additional simplification: `ROS_IP` should be different for each device. `ROS_MASTER_URI` should be the same for each device.

**Comment by [raequin](https://answers.ros.org/users/33937/raequin/) on 2018-08-01**:
This is a bit off topic, but wouldn't there be a problem if the robot has a `robot_state_publisher` node since `tf` does not support namespacing?  (Two robots would both want to publish to the tf topic.)